# Clear GET variables off of URL before submitting form

Tags: php, forms

The URL of a form includes some GET parameters.

The form submits via post to "" (the same page).

It turns out, that includes the GET parameters. Is there a way to submit to the same page without including all of the GET parameters?

Comment: Can you show us some code, like how yous submit the form, because I really doubt that its going to submit GET data with POST request.

Comment: @Apurv `<form action="page.php?foo=bar" method="POST">`, he wants to not be submitting `foo`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could use:

```
action="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']?>"
```

or:

```
action="<?php echo $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']?>"
```

See: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
action="?"
```

instead of

```
action=""
```

as you do it (if I understood correctly)

Answer (score 1):

Sure there is: use `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']` for action. `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` is Apache-specific.